# Need to update parameters in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two columns code1 and code2 in users model. I am trying to merge the values of the columns as code. I have written a migration file for that and I have removed code1 and code2. To work the old apps I need to accept code1 and code2 and combine it to get code. So I have permitted code1 and code2. But when I use old app I gets this error

```
unknown attribute 'code1' for User
```

In my controller I have wrote the following code

```
if user_params[:code1].present?
  user_params[:code] = user_params[:code1] + user_params[:code2]
  user_params.delete(:code1)
  user_params.delete(:code2)
end
```

But it is not working as expected. How can I support code1 in the old app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but try adding `attr_accessor :code1, :code2` in `User` Model

once you define `attr_accessor` in `User model` and permitted it on Controller, you can write callback in User model and write self.code = self.code1 + self.code2

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :code1, :code2

  before_validation :demo_callback

  def demo_callback
    self.code = self.code1 + self.code2
  end

end
```